# I am fine, or I am well, or I am good?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idioms, contemporary-english

In grade school, eons ago, I was taught to say "I am fine."   Today, most people say, "I am good."

Recently, I received scorn for an old man saying, "I am fine," as it was argued that "fine" would apply to a younger person, likely a female.

Where is consensus on this, and what would an acceptable response be?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/difference-between-im-fine-and-im-good

Comment: The answer is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "fine" can be used to mean "attractive", it isn't limited to that usage.  "I'm fine" is a very standard piece of language as far as I'm aware.